# How to read a ".TAB" file

Tags: r, web-scraping, download

I am trying to find a way to retrieve data from Harvard Dataverse website through R.  I am using "dataverse" and "dvn" packages, among others.  Many of the data files end with ".tab", although they are not formatted as normal tab-delimited text.

I have done this:

```
library(dataverse)   

## 01. Using the dataverse server and making a search
Sys.setenv("DATAVERSE_SERVER" ="dataverse.harvard.edu")

## 02. Loading the dataset that I chose, by url
doi_url <- "https://doi.org/10.7910/DVN/ZTCWYQ"
my_dataset <- get_dataset(doi_url)

## 03. Grabbing the first file of the dataset
## which is named "001_AppendixC.tab"
my_files <- my_dataset$files$label
my_file <- get_file(my_files[1], doi_url)
AppendixC <- tempfile()
writeBin(my_file, AppendixC)

read.table(AppendixC)
> Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
> line 1 did not have 2 elements
> In addition: Warning message:
> In read.table(AppendixC) :
> line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls
```

Any hint?

Comment: Can you post a simple piece of code that replicates the error? You probably need to address each file type uniquely.

Comment: Just added the code in the post body

Comment: It's definitely a file that can be opened in MS Excel... but not sure how to get R to read it.  Looking through the dataverse documentation...

Comment: The R `read.delim` function is designed for tab-delimited data.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `dataverse::get_file()` **returns the file in a raw binary format**. The easiest way to load it into memory is to write it to a tempfile with `writeBin()` and then read that file with the appropriate import/read function.

**Here is a function that should automagically read it into memory**:

```
# Uses rio, which automatically chooses the appropriate import/read
# function based on file type.
library(rio)
install_formats()                       # only needs to run once after
                                        # pkg installation

load_raw_file <- function(raw, type) {

  match.arg(
    arg = type,
    choices = c(      
      "csv", "tab", "psc", "tsv", "sas7bdat",
      "sav", "dta", "xpt", "por", "xls", "xlsx",
      "R", "RData", "rda", "rds", "rec", "mtb",
      "feather", "csv.gz", "fwf"
    )
  )

  tmp <- tempfile(fileext = paste0(".", type))
  writeBin(as.vector(raw), tmp)
  out <- import(tmp)
  unlink(tmp)

  out
}
```

**Let's try it out with your file**, which is a an excel file.

```
library(dataverse)

raw <- get_file(
  "001_AppendixC.tab",
  "https://doi.org/10.7910/DVN/ZTCWYQ"
)

data <- load_raw_file(raw, "xlsx")
```

And look at the data:

```
str(data)

> 'data.frame': 132 obs. of  17 variables:
>  $ Country  : chr  "Afghanistan" "Albania" "Algeria" "Angola" ...
>  $ UN_9193  : chr  "37.4" "7.7" "9.1" "65.400000000000006" ...
>  $ UN_9901  : chr  "46.1" "7.2" "10.7" "50" ...
>  $ UN_0709  : chr  "24.6" "9.6999999999999993" "7.5" "23.7" ...
>  $ UN_1416  : chr  "23" "4.9000000000000004" "4.5999999999999996" "14" ...
>  $ stu90_94 : chr  "51.3" "37.200000000000003" "22.9" "52.9" ...
>  $ stu98_02 : chr  "54.7" "39.200000000000003" "23.6" "47.1" ...
>  $ stu06_10 : chr  "51.3" "23.1" "13.2" "29.2" ...
>  $ stu12_16 : chr  "40.9" "17.899999999999999" "11.7" "37.6" ...
>  $ wast90_94: chr  "11.5" "9.4" "7.1" "7.9" ...
>  $ wast98_02: chr  "13.4" "12.2" "3.1" "8.6999999999999993" ...
>  $ wast06_10: chr  "8.9" "9.4" "4.0999999999999996" "8.1999999999999993" ...
>  $ wast12_16: chr  "9.5" "6.2" "4.0999999999999996" "4.9000000000000004" ...
>  $ UM1992   : chr  "16.8" "3.7" "4.5" "22.6" ...
>  $ UM2000   : chr  "13.7" "2.6" "4" "21.7" ...
>  $ UM2008   : chr  "11" "1.8" "2.9" "19.2" ...
>  $ UM2015   : chr  "9.1" "1.4" "2.6" "15.7" ...
```

Comment: great answer.  I should have started with ?get_file to see what it was returning